# Core Data Predicate a Many to Many relationship for sectionNameKeyPath reoccurrence

Tags: iphone, core-data, nsfetchedresultscontroller

I have a Core Data model that looks like this…

Event <<-------->> Date

The idea being that an Event can have many Dates and a Date can have many Events. I need my tableview to list Events with SectionHeaders displaying the Dates.

My issue is that I don't know how to set this up so that an Event can reoccur each time a new date is displayed in the SectionHeader.

When I setup my Predicate to collect all the Dates for each Event it does not allow for a duplication of the event when setting the sectionNameKeyPath on the FRC.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of a many to many relationship, wouldn't it make sense to just have a date property of your event object, and just look up all events for a particular date? I'd imagine this is possible using `NSPredicate`.

The minor downside is you'd have to have an entry for each reoccurring event and modify all of them when one is changed. On the upside this is functionally beneficial as it allows users to modify individual events in series, or cancel / delete an event without effecting the rest in the series.

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't fit the data I have which is more complicated than what I outlined in my question. In short the dates for each event can fall into one of three categories; a single event, an event which falls on none consecutive days or times and and event which spans a range with a beginning and end date marking the span. I know how to arrange the last two properties into sets so that they correspond with an event but I can't normalise the data so that the events are multiplied as necessary for each section head.

Answer (score 0):

Jim,

The NSFetchedResultsController is restricted to just a single entity. Hence, many complex queries are not possible or require complex queries using sub-queries. In my experience, unless your data model fits into this narrow design, then you'll have trouble. I retreat to listening for the context did save notification and processing the objects that change or are inserted directly.

Andrew

Comment: It seems odd that something that should be so simple is so complicated. If you look at the Calendar App in List view you will notice how an appointment which spans a range of dates gets repeated below each section header, this is effectively what I'm trying to achieve. I can model all the date data but I just can't figure to how to map it to the section headers. I think I might try creating a calendar and predicating the event dates data against that entity without a relationship.

Comment: Jim, I would disagree. Core Data does it differently than most other database systems. In this case, it sounds like your data model is not quite right for Core Data. With some simple changes, it can probably be a better fit. For example, due to the way bindings and the NSFetchedResultsController work, data will sometimes be duplicated in an entity. You may have to do this to render your calendar. Andrew

Comment: I'm not sure I follow you. My issue is that Data is not getting duplicated on Events entity when the Date entity validates that it should. It also doesn't help that SectionNameKeyPath doesn't accept a NSSet (to many relationship) as a valid key.

Comment: Jim, I've reread your problem. I think you are better served managing your table view the "old fashioned way." If there are dynamic inserts of dates, you can either listen for the did save notifications and insert them yourself at the right location or just reload the data. Andrew